# Kubernetes StorageClassName: quantities must match the regular expression

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, kustomize

I have the following `pv.yaml` Kubernetes/Kustomization file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: myapp-common-pv
  namespace: myapp
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp-common-pv
    app.kubernetes.io/component: common-pv
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: myapp
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: /myapp_nfs_share
    server: <omitted for security purposes>
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myapp-common-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  volumeName: myapp-common-pv
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30gi
```

When I run this I get:

```
persistentvolume/myapp-common-pv unchanged
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "/Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/k8s/pv": PersistentVolumeClaim in version "v1" cannot be handled as a PersistentVolumeClaim: v1.PersistentVolumeClaim.Spec: v1.PersistentVolumeClaimSpec.StorageClassName: Resources: v1.ResourceRequirements.Requests: unmarshalerDecoder: quantities must match the regular expression '^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$', error found in #10 byte of ...|ge":"30gi"}},"storag|..., bigger context ...|teMany"],"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"30gi"}},"storageClassName":"","volumeName":"myapp-common|...
```

Above, `<omitted for security purposes>` *is* a valid IP address, I just removed it for...security purposes.

I'm setting `storageClassName: ""` due to [this article explaining why its necessary](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares).

**Can anyone spot what's wrong with my `pv.yaml` file?** And what I need to do (*specifically!*) to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> quantities must match the regular expression '^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$', error found in #10 byte of ...|ge":"30gi"}}

Change

```
storage: 30gi
```

to

```
storage: 30Gi
```

The `Gi` part must follow the [predefined units](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#setting-requests-and-limits-for-local-ephemeral-storage).

Comment: Thanks @Jonas (+1) -- just curious, what do Ei, Pi, Ti, Gi, Mi and Ki all stand for?

Comment: See e.g. Gibibyte on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units

Comment: for me i had kep GIb for that it was failing once i changed from GIb -> Gi started working